# How to combine impress.js and parallax.js?

Tags: javascript, parallax, impress.js, parallax.js

I would like to use the presentation script impress.js (http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/its) to create a website. Now I would like to also use parallax.js (http://stephband.info/jparallax/) to create a parallax effect using all the images in one "step" of the presentation. Now I am struggling when trying to include the parallax effect into the impress.js. The problem seems to be that impress.js is in a 3D space while parallex.js uses margin and position to move the elements.
Now my question is, does anybody have experience in combining these two tools or might have an idea which parallex effect might work in a 3D space?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a second div (with fixed height and width) in your impress step container, which surrounds the parallax listing. Have you tried that? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Flowtime.js](https://github.com/marcolago/flowtime.js).it Supports parallax,however you will lose some essential features which are in impress and not here.